# Store correct timezone for Mailchimp member subscribed via API

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using [php code like the snippet here](http://www.codexworld.com/add-subscriber-to-list-mailchimp-api-php/), and sending the location object using `"location":{"latitude": "27.4333","longitude": "77.1"}`.

Unfortunately the response I get has the GMT offset incorrect. I get GMT+6 whereas it should be GMT+05:30.

Is there any other way to store the correct timezone in Mailchimp?

Related:
I used [ipapi](https://ipapi.co/) to get the latitude and longitude. Are there any better free services for getting the IP and location?

Thanks.